# unable to access databases i created on google compute engine from local computer

Tags: mysql, mongodb, ubuntu, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I created **mongodb** and **mysql** databases on **Google Cloud Compute Engine** they are running well on the server, but i want to access them from my local computer, i am getting errors, can anyone help me to find out where i'm doing wrong in configurations ?.

**Firewall rules**

[image: Firewall rules]
**Ports status**

[image: Ports status]
**IP Bind**

[image]
[image]

**errors**
mongo
[image]

mysql

[image]

Comment: Is the IP address private or public IP?

Comment: @jjayadeep yes it is my external ip but it was not a static ip, i got  static one and attached to the instance. Even if i added firewall rules to get open ports not worked. i have no idea why, i verified with https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/, then i used "sudo ufw allow 27017" and "sudo ufw allow 3306" then ports showed as open. that was the issue. thanks